# Can STDIN of the child process be changed by the parent after initialisation?

Tags: winapi

It is possible to do that at initialisation time with LPSTARTUPINFO struct, but can it be done after the child process is already running. The goal is for the child process to read from STDIN, but then parent every so often should cut in, and send something via a different anonymous pipe.

Comment: I cannot understand why you would need this. The parent is in control of the child's STDIN. Why would you ever need more than one channel?

Comment: It's in control during initialisation, right? I'm talking about changing it after initialisation. Never did i ask about having more than one channel.

Comment: Sure you did. You want the child process to listen to a different STDIN. That's the second channel. But why not just write everything down the one original channel?

Comment: Ok, please let me know how to read CONIN$ of another window (where the child's process is started), then, of course, there'd be no problem to read that and write that down the one original channel.

Comment: A process can use `CreateFile` with `CONIN$`, and then pass that handle to `SetStdHandle`. But that's just for the calling process. I don't think you can modify a different process from the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not launch the child in the same console window as the parent?  Then you can read the keyboard input in the parent and pipe it to the child, occasionally interspersed with your other input.

If your parent process is a GUI app then write an additional console app to do the job.

If the child must run in a separate window you can use the same trick: create a new process in its own window that shares a window with the child.

Comment: I thought about this three tier system myself actually, will probably go with that.I guess that i got too used to doing things POSIX way, where this is much more straight forward, and when i came up with this limitation my thought wasn't "it must be impossible", but rather "i must not have found the correct function". Sad that i was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The parent cannot change the child's STDIN after it has created the child process.  However, the parent can create an inheritable pipe and pass its handle value to the child as a command line parameter, then the child can extract that value and use the pipe as needed, without affecting its normal STDIN. The child can call `PeekNamedPipe()` periodically, or use a worker thread, to monitor the pipe for incoming data.